# MySQL Connector field() Auto-Conversion to Lasso Types?

Tags: lasso-lang

In Lasso 8 with MySQL connector, the `field()` method seemed to always return a string type, regardless of what data was in the column, or the column's data type. The exception might've been BLOB columns, which might've returned a bytes type. (I don't recall at the moment.)

In Lasso 9 I see that the `field()` method returns an integer type for integer columns. This is causing some issue with conditionals where I tested for `'1'` instead of `1`.

Is Lasso really using the MySQL data type, or is Lasso just interpreting the results?

Is there any documentation as to what column types are cast to what Lasso data types?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's easy to find out what column types Lasso reports.
With a table looking like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `addressb` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `type` enum('commercial','residential') COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
 `street` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `city` varchar(25) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `state` char(2) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `zip` char(10) COLLATE utf8_swedish_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT NULL,
 `image` blob,
 `created` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_swedish_ci;
```

You can get the reported column types like this:

```
inline(-database = 'testdb', -sql = "SELECT * FROM address") => {^
    with col in column_names do {^
        column(#col) -> type
        '<br />'
    ^}
^}
```

Result:

id integer
type string
street string
city string
state string
zip null
image bytes
created string

As you can see, everything is reported as string except the integer and blob field. Plus the zip field that in this record happen to contain NULL and is reported as such.

When doing comparisons it is always a good idea to make sure you're comparing apples with apples. That is, making sure you're comparing values of the same type. Also, to check if there's content I always go for size.
`string(column('zip')) -> size > 0 ?`

Answer (score 1):

Lasso is using the information MySQL gives it about the column type to return the data as a corresponding Lasso type. Not sure of all the mechanics underneath. Lasso 8 may have done the same thing for integers, but Lasso 8 also allowed you to compare integers and strings with integer values. (In fact, Lasso 8 even allowed for `array->get('1')` - that's right, a string for the index!).

I don't know of any documentation about what fields are what. Anecdotally, I can tell you that while MySQL decimal and float fields are treated as Lasso decimals, MySQL doubles are not. (I also don't believe MySQL date(time) fields come over as Lasso dates, though that would be awesome.)

Answer (score 0):

In addition, NULL are returned as NULL in 9, whereas in 8 and earlier it was empty string.  Beware of comparison of:

`field('icanhaznull') == ''`

If the field contains a NULL value, the above evaluates as TRUE in 8, and FALSE in 9.

That may mean altering your schema for columns toggling between NOT NULL and not.  Or you may prefer to cast the field to string:

`string(field('icanhaznull')) == ''`

[Testing a field or var against the empty string](http://www.lassosoft.com/Migration-Guide-What-Has-Changed#heading17)